# Black border around iPhone 4 display

Tags: iphone, screen

[image]

I just got my developer certificate from apple and I tried to add provisioning to my iPhone so I connected it to my macbook pro and everything went fine suddenly I started to get a black thin border around my screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's standard behaviour on all iPhones, I see the same border on my phone. It is not related to developer certificates/provisioning.